# add content to model on createRecord()

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I got an Ember model that looks like this:

```
App.Collection = DS.Model.extend({
    types: DS.hasMany('App.Type')
});
```

It's obligated to have 4 types in a collection.

I want to make sure that everytime the createRecord() get's called, the model creates 4 new types as well.

How can I do this?

Thanx!